# Return type from Scala method to Java

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, casting

I have a scala class that returns the following...

```
val resultMap:java.util.Map[java.lang.Long,java.util.List[com.mine.MyObject]]
```

The problem is, when it is called from Java I get...

```
Map<java$lang$Long, Object>
```

...which Java does not understand. Is there something I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there are some things missing in the question. Because I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `import collection.JavaConverters._`

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html